# get objects from List using Multi Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have a List of 100,000 objects. Want to read the List as fast as possible.

Had split them into multiple small List each of 500 objects

```
    List<List<String>> smallerLists = Lists.partition(bigList, 500);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(smallerLists.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < smallerLists.size();i++) {   
        MyXMLConverter xmlList = new MyXMLConverter(smallerLists.get(i));
        executor.execute(xmlList);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}
```

MyXMLConverter.java
Again using Executors of 50 threads, to process these 500 objects List.

```
public MyXMLConverter(List<String> data){
  this.data = data;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        convertLine();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}

public void convertLine(){
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
  for(int i = 0; i < data.size();i++) {
     MyConverter worker = new MyConverter(list.get(i));
     executor.execute(worker);
  }
  executor.shutdown();
  while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}

}
```

It's consuming lot of time in fetching the objects from List. Is there any better way to do this ? Please suggest.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Since processing time of each item may vary, it'd be better to just have each worker thread pull the next item to processes directly from the main list, in order to keep all threads busy at the end.

Multi-threaded pulling from a shared list is best done using one of the concurrent collections. In your case, [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) would be a prime candidate.

So, copy your list into a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` (or build the "list" directly as a queue), and let your threads call [`poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#poll%28%29) until it return `null`.

---

If building the list of 100000 elements take time too, you can even kickstart the process by allowing worker threads to begin their job *while* building the queue. For this, you'd use a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), and the workers would call [`take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29).

You'd then add a special element to the queue to mark the end, and when a worker get the end-marker, it would put it back in the queue for the next worker, then exit.

Comment: For reference, the finishing worker threads by special elements is usually called "Poison Pill", just for easier googling

Answer (score 1):

There is two main problem

- Your code create 200 * 50 + 50 threads
- Most of them do nothing in infinite loop: `while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}`

I suggest to use something like this.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(COUNT_OF_YOUR_PROCESSOR_CORESS * 2);

    List<Future<?>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();

    for(String currentString : bigList) {
        MyConverter worker = new MyConverter(currentString);
        Future<?> future = executor.submit(worker);
        futureList.add(future);
    }

    Collections.reverse(futureList);
    for (Future<?> future : futureList){
        future.get();
    }

    executor.shutdown(); //No worries. All task already executed here
```

Or if you Java 8 addict then

```
bigList.parallelStream().forEach(s -> new MyConverter(s).run());
```

Comment: Yes I guess the same, while (!executor.isTerminated()) {} is causing the delay, but i don't find any alternative ? will there be any improvement with invokeAll() here ?

Comment: Yes. It helps. And do not partition your list. I will edit my answer by adding my version of your code.